# How to redirect all request to subfolder with it's own .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I know such questions has been answered a lot of time, but neither of found answers works for me.
I have following url `http://dummy.com/api` to access my root folder where I am going to have my project (Laravel project).
I am deploying to the remote hosting so I have no acceess to the parent directories.
My project (simple Laravel project) consists from a lot of folders, which by the way should be placed in parent directories (`app,bootstrap,config...`) and public folder where main `index.php` of Laravel project is located.
So I have url like this `http://dummy.com/api/public/index.php`
This directory includes it own `.htaccess` file with following content.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L
```

This stuff is required by the laravel.

So I need all requests to the `http://dummy.com/api` have been redirected to the `public/` subfolder(index.php by default).
For example `http://dummy.com/api/users` should be really `http://dummy.com/api/pulbic/users`.
But this should be transparent for the user and not changed to the real url.
I have tried a lot of different configurations also from here [Common .htaccess Redirects](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489)

But this doesn't work for me. Please help to create such rules to have desired result.
Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Is the .htaccess show located in `/api/public/` directory? Does `/api/` also have a .htaccess?

Comment: I have tried to configure `htacces` inside root directory in order to get desired result, and yes inside /api/public there is another htaccess file that I have provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .htaccess in `/api/` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you !! how do you do this ?) I have seen a lof your answers for such questions) Thank you again!